# how work mongodb with file js?

Tags: mongodb

I test node.js and mongodb. Everything works in the terminal, but not when I create a js file. Whatever its contents, I get an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.
>   Example : db.adminCommand("listDatabases");

What to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which are you using? The mongodb shell? Or the node in non interactive? Especially for the second one then show some code as then only thing you list here suggests the shell and nothing to do with nodejs at all.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake: you have to exit (after mongo) in the terminal before executing a file with node fichier.js.